# Does attribute-based access control with SpEL instead of XACML still exist?

Tags: spring, spring-security, abac

I'm looking to implement ABAC in an existing Spring Security project and found this GitHub page https://github.com/simplicii/spring-abac-sample which includes both a link to a jar SNAPSHOT as well as a reference documentation. However besides that and these three mentions of it https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues?q=is%3Aissue+abac+is%3Aclosed I can't seem to find anything else related to it.

Does anyone know what happened to it? I don't suppose it's safe to use the SNAPSHOT from 2017? Was it deprecated and if so, does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look here. https://medium.com/@agamgupta1988/xacml-with-wso2-identity-server-bbd9f5c57dad

Answer (score 0):

The pull-request below answers my own question, abac for spring-security was never fully implemented and has to be leveraged through e.g. SpEL

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/4277